# Thread is not getting Destroyed

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, thread-synchronization

I am working on a Multithreaded system here's my code
class demo is defined in .h file

when the loop from the main function is executed second time the COMMENT1 below takes the previous value

doesn't closing handle closes the thread?

```
int threadentry(void* data)
{
   demo* inst=(demo*) data;
   cout << "Value of inst  "<<hex << &inst<< endl;
   string request;
   cin>>request;
   if(request==play)
   {
      inst->play;  
      cout << "Value of inst  "<<hex << &inst<< endl;
      // COMMENT1 here when the thread is executed second time from the main it is taking previous value
   }
}

int main()
{
   while(1)
   {
      demo* inst=new demo();
      cout << "Value of inst  "<<hex << &inst<< endl;  //value is coming different from above
      HANDLE threads;
      DWORD threadId1;
      if ((threads = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)threadentry,
         (void *)inst, 0, &threadId1)) == NULL)
        return -1;
      //here is some Processing of data and after processing I close the handle
      CloseHandle(threads);
      delete inst;
      system("pause");
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at std::thread?

Answer (score 2):

No -- closing a handle to a thread does not destroy the thread itself. The thread should *exit* (either by calling `ExitThread` or by just returning from the thread function) when it's finished doing its job.

In emergencies, you *can* use `TerminateThread` to kill a thread, but that should be reserved for true emergencies -- it can leave the process in an unstable state, so it should generally be avoided, and if you have to use it, you probably want to shut down the process as soon afterwards as possible.

Also note that in a program that uses the standard library, it's not really safe to use `CreateThread` directly -- you should call `_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex` instead. These do some setup to allow thread-safe use of standard library functions that use static storage (e.g., `strtok` and `mktime`, but there are quite a few more).

Comment: I want to close the thread as soon as I am Closing the handle Can i use TerminateThread here
Do I risk to incur a memory leak in this case?

Comment: Do you want the thread to run or not? If you don't want it to run, don't start it. If you do want it to run, let it run to completion. Yes, you *could* start it, then immediately terminate it -- but doing so makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Drop all those "(type)foo" casts, they are forcing the compiler to accept things that in reality don't fit. You will have to fix a few errors there by replacing things with the proper type. For the context pointer passed to the thread, the conversion from `demo*` to `void*` is implicit. The correct cast to reverse this is `static_cast<demo*>(data)`. If you want, you can use the a static cast for the implicit conversion, too. There are missing return values in functions, too, the only case that is allowed is in main(). The reason I mention th s is that formally, anything can happen in your program, because these things cause undefined behaviour.

Then, you are outputting the "value of inst" but actually outputting the address of local variables called "inst", which is something different. This probably just adds to your confusion.

Now, coming to your problem, CloseHandle() does not stop the thread. It only releases your handle. What you want is WaitForSingleObject() or one of its brethren instead.

Comment: Yeah I agree with the addressing issue you prolly want cout << "Value of inst  "<<hex << inst<< endl; or even cout << "Value of inst  "<<hex << *inst<< endl;

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake
but if I want to terminate the thread from the main function(where I am calling the closeHandle) can I use terminate thread there?

Comment: Search the web for "thread cancellation" and you will find that forceful termination bears several risks concerning the state of shared data. Don't do it unless you really, really know what you are doing and specifically wrote the code in the thread to be cancellation-safe. You're not there yet, so tell the thread to terminate and wait for it, or even leave it running in the background. Note that on program termination, all other threads will be cancelled anyway, in case that is your concern.